# Is there a way to change the parent content for a popup in WinUI3?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3

In WinUI3 it seems that you are unable to modify the duration of a tooltip (similar to how WPF allowed a duration change with the `ToolTipService.ShowDuration`).

As such, I'm attempting to replicate the behavior using a Popup control such that the Popup will remain visible as long as the mouse is hovered over an element (utilizing the element's `OnPointerEntered` / `OnPointerExited` events to modify the `IsOpen` property of the Popup).

This displays the Popup correctly, however in my case the Popup exists inside a `Grid` which is inside the `ListView.ItemTemplate` for a `ListView`.  ala:

```xml
<ListView>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <TextBlock/>
      <Popup/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Thus the popup only overlays the `<Grid>`, but still gets clipped within the region of the `DataTemplate`.

I'd like to have the popup overlay the `<ListView>` itself instead - is there a way to specify which content the popup will overlay such that it will overlay the `<ListView>`?

Or even better - to have it overlay all elements of the Window (replicating the placement of a tooltip?)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the parent content for a popup in WinUI3?

Sure, you could place Popup at same level as `ListView` in current page. And listen ListView item `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` event then pass current item datacontext to popup control.

**Xaml**

```
<ListView
    Margin="0,10,0,45"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
    Visibility="Visible">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Vertical"
                PointerEntered="StackPanel_PointerEntered"
                PointerExited="StackPanel_PointerExited">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Id" Text="{Binding ID}" />
                <TextBox
                    x:Name="FirstName"
                    GettingFocus="FirstName_GettingFocus"
                    Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="LastName" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<Popup
    x:Name="PopupTip"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Popup.ChildTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Bottom" />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Popup.ChildTransitions>

    <StackPanel
        Width="150"
        Height="80"
        Background="LightGray"
        CornerRadius="4">
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="InfoLabel"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding ID}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void StackPanel_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ItemDataContext = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    PopupTip.DataContext = ItemDataContext;
    PopupTip.IsOpen = true;
  
}

private void StackPanel_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupTip.DataContext = null;
    PopupTip.IsOpen = false;
}
```